# Content Organiser and the Send To button in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-organizer, drop-off-library

Is there any way in SharePoint Online to get the 'Send To' option back now the Ribbon has been removed from the 'new experience'?

It's a bit of a pain when you want to use content organiser that it now seems the only way to use it is to upload directly into it, rather than being able to move items from another library into it with the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'Modern Experience' you have the option to 'Move/Copy' file or folder. Just select the file/folder and from to top menu bar you can see these option or you can just right click on item and see the pop-up menu. See below image.

[image]

Comment: Good in theory, the problem is none of those options show siblings of the library you're in, just folders underneath it (so, completely useless like most SPO features).

Comment: The problem could be you are not following any of the site. If you follow any of the site/subsite where you want to move/copy you data, you'll see those options enabled.

Comment: For me its like following image. http://imgur.com/a/gXKPS

Comment: Ah right yeah I was thinking that 'Places' heading had to have some sort of specific meaning. Still seems a bit backward from MS as then you have to make sure users are following the relevant locations.

Comment: Sometimes MS got tricky, and wants you think out of the box. :) cheers..

Comment: One last thing to note is that the 'Places' you're following only show for Copy, not Move, so still basically useless for content organiser purposes as you'll then have duplicate documents all over the place.

Comment: Didn't checked that option, thanks for bringing it in notice. May be SP PnP community call can help us regarding this issue.